# eslint - async arrow function return value error

Tags: javascript, typescript

Currently experiencing a little bit of an annoyance rather than a problem. I have the following function:

```
export const getLoginSession = async (req: NextApiRequest): Promise<undefined | User> => {
  const token = getTokenCookie(req)

  if (!token) return

  const session = await Iron.unseal(token, TOKEN_SECRET, Iron.defaults)
  const expiresAt = session.createdAt + session.maxAge * 1000

  // Validate the expiration date of the session
  if (Date.now() > expiresAt) {
    throw new Error('Session expired')
  }

  return session
}
```

and `eslint(consistent-return)` is telling me: `Async arrow function expected no return value.`

I thought, why not try it like this instead:

```
export const getLoginSession = async (req: NextApiRequest): Promise<undefined | User> => {
  const token = getTokenCookie(req)

  if (token) {
    const session = await Iron.unseal(token, TOKEN_SECRET, Iron.defaults)
    const expiresAt = session.createdAt + session.maxAge * 1000

    if (Date.now() > expiresAt) {
    throw new Error('Session expired')
    }

    return session
  }
}
```

but then I am getting eslint's: `Expected to return a value at the end of async arrow function.`

A fix is to return to the first iteration and return `false` from `if (!token) return false` which fixes the problem.

My question is

1. is that the best way to handle it when we usually wouldn't explicitly return false?
2. I am new to Typescript, is a return type of `Promise<undefined | User>` appropriate?

type User contains id: string, username: string, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question, yes there is a better way. You should always reject the promise if the result of the promise is not of the type you expect it to be. Returning undefined will still have the caller of that promise handle this case and it becomes a bit confusing in my experience.

I would change it for something like this:

```js
export const getLoginSession = async (req: NextApiRequest): Promise<User> => { // <-- this promise will return a user or throw
  const token = getTokenCookie(req)

  if (!token) {
    throw new Error('invalid token') // <-- unexpected we should throw
  }

  const session = await Iron.unseal(token, TOKEN_SECRET, Iron.defaults)
  const expiresAt = session.createdAt + session.maxAge * 1000

  // Validate the expiration date of the session
  if (Date.now() > expiresAt) {
    throw new Error('Session expired')
  }

  return session
}
```

This way we have a better control flow and it's easy to reason about.

```js
try {
  const session = await getLoginSession(req)
  // do something with the session
} catch (error) {
  // handle the error
  console.log(error)
}
```

About the consistent return, it's because you didn’t defined a value after the return. So `return false` works but `return undefined` or `return void 0` will also work.

From the docs:

> require return statements to either always or never specify values

ref: [consistent-return](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/consistent-return)

Answer (score 0):

In the below code, `session` is not existing when you are returning, `const/let` values are block-scoped hence `session` scope only exists inside that `if` block not outside of it. You need to either. return inside from `if` block and return error promise or just do the fallback when `token` is getting `falsy` and if not then return the `session`

```
if (token) {
    const session = await Iron.unseal(token, TOKEN_SECRET, Iron.defaults)
    const expiresAt = session.createdAt + session.maxAge * 1000

    if (Date.now() > expiresAt) {
    throw new Error('Session expired')
    }

    return session
  }
```